# How to bind Openweather map API data in DataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using [DataTables](https://datatables.net) and wanted to show my cities data in it, I am failing to do it.

For Example If I call [this URL](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?id=2643741,2644688,2633352,2654675,2988507,2990969,2911298,2925535,2950159,3120501,3128760,5128581,4140963,4930956,5106834,5391959,5368361,5809844,4099974,4440906&appid=de6d52c2ebb7b1398526329875a49c57&units=metric) Then I get the cities data in JSON (from openweathers map api). I want to simply show this data on my datatables. 
Please help.

My code:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?id=2643741,2644688,2633352,2654675,2988507,2990969,2911298,2925535,2950159,3120501,3128760,5128581,4140963,4930956,5106834,5391959,5368361,5809844,4099974,4440906&appid=de6d52c2ebb7b1398526329875a49c57&units=metric",
dataType: "json",
success: function (result, status, xhr) {

    $('#weatherTable').DataTable({
        data: JSON.stringify(result),
        columns: [
            { data: 'id' },
            { data: 'name' }
        ],
        "pageLength": 3
    });
},
error: function (xhr, status, error) {
    console.log("Result: " + status + " " + error + " " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText)
}
```

});

I am simply getting error:

> DataTables warning: table id=weatherTable - Requested unknown
>   parameter 'id' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this
>   error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Please help?

Comment: Why do you stringify the data before trying to plug it into the table?

Comment: @Falk i tried it without stiringify but still it did not worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ajax.dataSrc` option to specify property containing table data.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: {

        url: 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?id=2643741,2644688,2633352,2654675,2988507,2990969,2911298,2925535,2950159,3120501,3128760,5128581,4140963,4930956,5106834,5391959,5368361,5809844,4099974,4440906&appid=de6d52c2ebb7b1398526329875a49c57&units=metric',
        dataSrc: 'list',
        method: 'POST'
    },
    columns: [
        { data: "id" },
        { data: "name" },
        { data: "main.temp" }
    ]                       
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/n3wm2yxe/3/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: thank you.One more thing- how to bind 'temp' under 'main' node for each of these cities in datatables?